# Far+ Adjective or Much +Adjective

Tags: comparative

Which sentence is correct.
1.Harry's watch is far more expensive than mine.
2.Harry's watch is much more expensive than mine.

Comment: _Far more_ and _much more_ mean the same.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. But see [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far+more+likely%2Cmuch+more+likely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing that we're ***much more likely*** to use ***much*** than ***far*** in such contexts.